# What are some resources to learn about the best practices while building URL's for a website?

Tags: php, url, resources, web

This is a follow-up question to [Why are the query parameters for many websites(MySQL) very cryptic long integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470441/why-are-the-query-parameters-for-many-websitesmysql-very-cryptic-long-integers). In terms of security and scalability. Please cite any resources(online/offline).

Comment: This is probably too vague to answer. Can you come up with a specific case?

Comment: when writing URL's for dynamic user-generated content website like twitter, each post of a user is given some long integer. In same way what things should I consider, when deciding data types in MySQL table or when writing rewrite rules in mod_rewrite for my website.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of security and scalability you can use whatever urls you imagine.

It's usually human readability and and usability or (more often) search engine friendship that affects URL building rules.

Say, PHP.NET famous [php.net/echo](http://php.net/echo) feature giving fast and easy access to function description. That's the reason to make such urls, not security.

Answer (score 1):

Security and scalability have little to do with the way an URL is formed. Some sites do use cryptic URLs as a measure for securing pictures (e.g. Facebook), this type of security is generally frowned upon, as everyone knowing the URL through various ways (browser cache, proxy cache, ...) can access the supposedly protected resource.

While a clean URL helps the search-engine-optimization, it usually means slower response and thus a degraded scalability. Consider an URL http://example.com/user/Lars, showing you the profile page of my profile. If my account is linked in the database not by my accountname but by a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) (some arbitrary number), the system first has to query the user table for my surrogate key in order to get the rest of the information. This degrades performance, as one more table has to be queried.

Comment: ...Unless the surrogate key is indexed, in which case the performance would be at least equal while resolving ambiguity (which "Lars"?) at the same time. Also, sharelockers (RapidShare and friends) use the "/ID/Filename" structure to add security through obscurity.

Comment: Yes, you may speed things up by indexing, but for a high-performance site like twitter, it is still better to use the primary keys directly. Integer-Searches are generally faster than string-searches, and indexing those will speed them up, too.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I don't think your answer makes much sense and you seem to be contradicting yourself: the surrugate key can be the primary key (auto-incremented number for instance) and identifies the exact "Lars" and not `n` "Lars".

Comment: I beg to differ - as I said, a search for a string is slower than a search for an integer. This is also true for indexes. So by accessing my profile via my surrogate, integer primary key is faster than by using my name as a primary key.

Comment: Your last sentence really got me confused - I though you were saying that by using a surrogate key you were degrading performance. I'm sorry for the misinterpretation. =)

Answer (score 1):

While I agree completely with Col. Shrapnel answer there are a few cases where long "cryptic" IDs contribute to security and sometimes even scalability. Sharelockers (RapidShare and friends) usually employ the `/ID/Filename` structure in their URLs to add security through obscurity, it would be far too easy for someone to test all integers or common filenames and get access to sensitive information.

Some people also apply some kind of checksum algorithm to their database IDs, this makes it harder for someone to figure out the underlying structure and "hide" certain kinds of information: I bet many people would be reluctant to pay for something online if the URL for the order was `/order/2/` for instance. Using checksums can also contribute for improved performance, since you can disregard invalid IDs without even having to query the database (useful when someone is brute-forcing your URLs).

Long IDs contribute to scalability, in the sense that they provide a wider range of possible numbers ([Slashdot had been a victim](http://slashdot.org/story/06/11/09/1534204/Slashdot-Posting-Bug-Infuriates-Haggard-Admins) of the "int(11) is more than enough for everyone" assumption twice - sorry can't find old story), and that's why you see Twitter and friends using different approaches nowadays.

When you use a wider ID you can also store more information, such as timestamps, IP / hostname that created the database record and so on, which can be crucial when you're running a distributed database setup. Take a look at the [MongoID class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) documentation to get a better idea how it works.